# Node redis GET method always returns null when used with async/await

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, redis, async-await, node-redis

Here's my code:

```
myFun = async (param: string) : Promise<string> => {
    const [host, port] = config.REDIS_URL.substr(8).split(":");
    const redisClient = redis.createClient({ host: host, port: Number(port) });
    const getAsync = promisify(redisClient.get).bind(redisClient);
    const test = await getAsync("userId");
}
```

This is not the complete code, I have only posted the relevant part. `promisify` is the method from util. The host and port are correct and I am able to connect to the redis server with the redis-cli. However, this method doesnt work. test is always null.

Comment: Are you sure that "userId" have value? you can check that through `redis-cli`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the code, the expected behaviour of the GET method is to return null when the key is not present.